# Setting a mint price for a contract extending a open zeplin ERC721URIStorage contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, chai

I have the following contract in Solidity that was working up until I added the line

`require(msg.value == mintPrice, "Not Enough Ether");`

```
// contracts/NFT.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract NFT is ERC721URIStorage {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

    uint256 mintPrice = 0.025 ether;

    constructor() ERC721("NFT", "ITM"){}

    function mint(address user, string memory tokenURI)
        public
        payable
        returns (uint256)
        {
            require(msg.value == mintPrice, "Not Enough Ether");
            _tokenIds.increment();

            uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
            _mint(user, newItemId);
            _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);

            return newItemId;
        }

}
```

I have the following chai test that fails saying not enough ether, but the address I am using is a hardhat address with tons of ether in it

```
describe("NFT", function () {
 it("Should return a transaction hash, async function", async function () {
   const NFT = await ethers.getContractFactory("NFT");
   const nft = await NFT.deploy();
   await nft.deployed();
   
   expect(await nft.mint('0xf3...fFb92266', "/Users/.../web3/nft-next-minter/public/test.json")).to.have.any.keys('hash');

   expect(await nft.tokenURI(1)).to.equal('/Users/.../web3/nft-next-minter/public/test.json');

 }); 
})
```

I am running `npx hardhat test --network localhost`

Not quite sure why I am getting this error, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
await nft.mint(
    '0xf3...fFb92266',
    "/Users/.../web3/nft-next-minter/public/test.json"
)
```

This JS snippet doesn't specify any `value` of the transaction, so it's sent with 0 value by default.

And since the contract is expecting the `value` to equal `mintPrice` (0.025 ether), it fails the `require()` condition, effectively reverting the transaction.

You can specify the value in the `overrides` param ([docs](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/#contract-functionsSend)).

```
await nft.mint(
    '0xf3...fFb92266',
    "/Users/.../web3/nft-next-minter/public/test.json",
    {value: ethers.utils.parseEther('0.025')}
)
```

Comment: Oh Awesome that makes sense, I was wondering how it would know how much to set the transaction to.